# How to check that excel cell value has spaces... excel 2007

Tags: vba, excel-2007, spaces

I have an Excel file that contains some values. I need to check if a cell value contains spaces. For example, sometimes a user will write some values in the cell but mistakenly press Enter or Space in the cell. I want to see if the cell value has spaces inside...
Please tell me how to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's say I type "ABC " in cell A1 (ABC followed by a space). Either of these formulas should help:

```
=LEN(A1)=LEN(TRIM(A1))

=EXACT(A1,TRIM(A1))
```

For a VBA version:

```
Function HasSpaces(rng As Excel.Range) As Boolean
  HasSpaces = Not (Len(rng.Value) = Len(Trim$(rng.Value)))
End Function
```

Sample usage:

```
Sub tst()
  Debug.Print HasSpaces(Range("A1"))
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 Though this will not catch cases where a user has mistakenly typed two or more spaces between words.

Comment: We could add an additional condition such as **InStr(rng.Value," ") > 0** to check for that.