# How to find enter and space between excel cell value-- excel 2007

Tags: vba, excel-2007, spaces, enter

How to find enter and space in the excel cell value by uisng VBA. For example if the cell value contain value like "Some value" then How to find that this cell contain space. In second case if the cellvalue contain Enter like while typing values in a cell if someone write "Some" and the press enter and then write "value" then how to find this enter.
I am using excel 2007
Thanks

Comment: Check some of your previous questions, some of the answers have sample code you can use here instead of just asking another question.

Comment: Hi JP, I am able to find spaces inside the string as well by using InStr(1, Cells(rowcounter + 2, counter).Value, " ") but I am not able to find How to check if the cell contain Enter.

Comment: This is simply an addition to your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8212637/how-to-check-that-excel-cell-value-has-spaces-excel-2007/8213020#8213020. Instr can be used in a variety of ways, including to find enter, look up chr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't hit enter to get a new line in Excel, you have to hit alt + Enter.  You can use the VBA constant vbLf in your Instr to find it.

Jesse

Comment: I believe you could also use Chr(10) or Chr(13) (I forget which)

Comment: I think it's chr(10), 13 is vbCr